# How to optimize and do this more readeable

Tags: c#, algorithm, for-loop, optimization, scalability

Hi everyone I have a question about how to make this more clean, reusable and readable. I have some data models (relics) and this has rarity and level. Depending on the level and the rarity it has to be grouped to later apply this in some math calculation. For this reason, I need to parse all my relics and check for the level and rarity and store in a var counter.

```cs
public double TotalGlobalBonus
{
    get
    {
        float commonRarityMultiplier = 20;
        float rareRarityMultiplier = 120;
        float epicRarityMultiplier = 320;
        float legendaryRarityMultiplier = 540;

        int rarityCommonLevel1 = 0;
        int rarityCommonLevel2 = 0;
        int rarityCommonLevel3 = 0;
        int rarityCommonLevel4 = 0;
        int rarityCommonLevel5 = 0;

        int rarityRareLevel1 = 0;
        int rarityRareLevel2 = 0;
        int rarityRareLevel3 = 0;
        int rarityRareLevel4 = 0;
        int rarityRareLevel5 = 0;

        int rarityEpicLevel1 = 0;
        int rarityEpicLevel2 = 0;
        int rarityEpicLevel3 = 0;
        int rarityEpicLevel4 = 0;
        int rarityEpicLevel5 = 0;

        int rarityLegendaryLevel1 = 0;
        int rarityLegendaryLevel2 = 0;
        int rarityLegendaryLevel3 = 0;
        int rarityLegendaryLevel4 = 0;
        int rarityLegendaryLevel5 = 0;

        foreach (RelicModel relic in this.equipedRelics)
        {
            switch (relic.rarity)
            {
                case RarityType.COMMON:
                    switch (relic.Level)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            rarityCommonLevel1++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            rarityCommonLevel2++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            rarityCommonLevel3++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            rarityCommonLevel4++;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            rarityCommonLevel5++;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case RarityType.RARE:
                    switch (relic.Level)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            rarityRareLevel1++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            rarityRareLevel2++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            rarityRareLevel3++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            rarityRareLevel4++;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            rarityRareLevel5++;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case RarityType.EPIC:
                    switch (relic.Level)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            rarityEpicLevel1++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            rarityEpicLevel2++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            rarityEpicLevel3++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            rarityEpicLevel4++;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            rarityEpicLevel5++;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case RarityType.LEGENDARY:
                {
                    switch (relic.Level)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            rarityLegendaryLevel1++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            rarityLegendaryLevel2++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            rarityLegendaryLevel3++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            rarityLegendaryLevel4++;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            rarityLegendaryLevel5++;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        double common = (commonRarityMultiplier / 100) * (rarityCommonLevel1 * 1 + rarityCommonLevel2 * 5 +
                                                          rarityCommonLevel3 * 10 + rarityCommonLevel4 * 20 +
                                                          rarityCommonLevel5 * 40);
        double rare = (rareRarityMultiplier / 100) * (rarityRareLevel1 * 1 + rarityRareLevel2 * 5 +
                                                        rarityRareLevel3 * 10 + rarityRareLevel4 * 20 +
                                                        rarityRareLevel5 * 40);
        double epic = (epicRarityMultiplier / 100) * (rarityEpicLevel1 * 1 + rarityEpicLevel2 * 5 +
                                                      rarityEpicLevel3 * 10 + rarityEpicLevel4 * 20 +
                                                      rarityEpicLevel5 * 40);
        double legendary = (legendaryRarityMultiplier / 100) * (rarityLegendaryLevel1 * 1 + rarityLegendaryLevel2 * 5 +
                                                                rarityLegendaryLevel3 * 10 + rarityLegendaryLevel4 * 20 +
                                                                rarityLegendaryLevel5 * 40);

        double final = common + rare + epic + legendary;

        return final;
    }
}
```

It is a really longe property and will grow if the number of levels grows, so this is not precisely scalable

Comment: Surely you just need a rarity enum and a level enum... so you get say epic level 5

Comment: I recommend using LINQ(Sum,Where,Count,SelectMany functions)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

Comment: Arrays for the level??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put all these values in a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) with keys of type `RarityType` and values of type `int[]`.

```
var rarity = new Dictionary<RarityType, int[]>();
rarity[RarityType.COMMON] = new int[6];
rarity[RarityType.RARE] = new int[6];
rarity[RarityType.EPIC] = new int[6];
rarity[RarityType.LEGENDARY] = new int[6];

foreach (RelicModel relic in this.equipedRelics)
{
    rarity[relic.rarity][relic.Level]++;
}
```

The first element of each array, the one having index = 0, is intended to be unused.

Comment: From the original code it looks like the RarityModel enum values start at 1 rather than 0 - so either that needs modifying or use _"rarity[relic.rarity][relic.Level-1]++;"_

Comment: Why not create a `Rarity` class? Then you can have an internal `Levels` array, and a property that converts the 1-based index to a 0-based index? This will also give you a place to store the multiplier. The class also would contain the method to compute the object's value based on the multiplier and the level values.

Comment: @JimMischel yes, there is ample space for improvements here!